# How to fix compound interest written in Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I am seriously pulling my hair out over this. I am writing a compound interest calculator in HTML and JS. The calculations are completely off. I don't know where I went wrong, since I get no error message.
My HTML code:

```
<label for="Start_amnt">Initial investment:</label>
<br>
<input type="number" id="Start_amnt" name="Start_amnt" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #FEFEFE; width:12em">
<br>
<label for="Percentage">Interest rate:</label> 
<br> 
<input type="number" id="Percentage" name="Percentage" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #FEFEFE; width:7em">%
<br>
<label>Time period</label>
        <br>
        <input placeholder="0" type="number" id="Period_Year" name="Period_Year" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #FEFEFE; width:5em"> <span>Years</span> 
        <input placeholder="0" type="number" id="Period_Month" name="Period_Month" STYLE="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #FEFEFE; width:5em"> <span>Months</span> 
            <br>
<button type="submit" onclick="calculate(Start_amnt.value, Percentage.value, Period_Year.value*12 + Period_Month.value)"> Calculate </button>
```

My JS code

```
function calculate(P,r,months) {
        for(i=0; i< months; i++){
            cashBack = P * Math.pow( 1 + r/100, months)
            P = cashBack
            console.log(cashBack);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the values of the inputs into numbers for the calculations - all inputs return string representations of the number the value indicates. If you don't parse them then the values are really strings and you will get funky outcomes.

```
function calculate(P,r,months) {
   const parsedP = parseInt(P, 10);
   const parsedR = parseInt(r, 10);
   let parsedMonths = parseInt(months, 10);

   for(i=0; i< parsedMonths ; i++){
     let cashBack = parsedP * Math.pow( 1 + parsedR /100, parsedMonths );
     parsedMonths  = cashBack;
     console.log(cashBack);
   }
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable at calculate.(The line "parsedMonths  = cashBack") and at HTMLButtonElement.onclick in the line ` <button type="submit" onclick="calculate(Start_amnt.value, Percentage.value, Period_Year.value*12 + Period_Month.value)"> Calculate </button>`

Comment: sorry - change the parsedMonths  const statements to let... my bad - that is occurring becuase you are re-assigning the parsedMonths  value. - also just note that I simply parsed the values as my answer indicated - i did not check the nature of the equation - check @Don R solution below to see if that impacts it as well.

Comment: That almost crashed my computer. It started counting to infinity thousands of times... I don't know if it's my code's fault or the suggestion you gave me. (I did check @Don R's solution and it did not work.)

Comment: The code did not work. Even after the fix you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're raising 1 + r/100 to the power of **months**; all you really want to do is multiply P by 1 + r/100:

```
cashBack = P * (1 + r/100)
```

EDIT: If you want the monthly amount on an annual interest rate, just further divide the rate by 12:

```
cashBack = P * (1 + r/100/12)
```

Comment: That didn't quite work. It still spits out gibberish, but different gibberish.

Comment: That's odd. What browser are you testing in? When I run my version in Firefox on an investment of 100, interest rate of 1 for 6 months the output is
101
102.01
103.0301
104.060401
105.10100501
106.1520150601
which is pretty much exactly what I expect.

Comment: I am running it on Chrome. The values you input did give that response, but with an initial investment of 100, interest rate of 10 for 12 months, the output is 110.00000000000001
121.00000000000003
133.10000000000005
146.41000000000008
161.0510000000001
177.15610000000012
194.87171000000015
214.3588810000002
235.79476910000022
259.37424601000026
285.3116706110003
313.84283767210036

Comment: Wait, are you wondering about the fractional part of the first value? This explains it as well as anything I've ever come across: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: The interest rate was supposed to be annual.

Comment: That's something you ought to have mentioned in your question. Here's a good explanation of how to calculate monthly compounding of an annual rate: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/compound-interest-calculator.php